# Code not running

Tags: python, time, calculator

I randomly thought of making a program to tell the difference between time and so far it works, although when I add another elif, the code doesn't run. The first part works, but if the numbers are the same the last elif statement doesn't run.

```
    num1 = input("Enter your first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter your second number: ")

    if num1 > num2:
        print (num1 - num2)

    elif num1<num2:
        print (num2 - num1)

    elif num1==num2:
        print ("There is no difference")
```

Comment: Please add the programming language and version your are using to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is because of string operation.

Try to replace the input code by this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
```

Comment: Although I want to add an error message if they enter a letter.  When I enter a letter the program just stops running and shows an error. I'm assuming it's not working because the code is expecting an integer.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You can catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

Are you running python2 or python3? Additionally, what are using for your time metric?

Your bug may be the result of `input()` having different functionality given the python version you are running

`input()` in python2 takes in a string and runs `eval()` on it which turns it into its most-likely type. For example, if I inputted 2 at the command line, python2 would take in 2 as a string, `"2"`, and then run `eval()` on it to turn it into an integer, `2`. [See the documentation for `input()` here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

`input()` in python3 on the other hand just takes in input from the command line and processes it directly as a string. So if you were to input 2 for `num1`, `num1` would live as `"2"` until otherwise specified. [See documentation for python3 `input()` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Thus, if you are running python2, this program should work fine. If you are running python3, you will run into error when you try to subtract strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Python 2 and if I encompass your program into a function like this, it works great.

```py
num1 = input("Enter your first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter your second number: ")

def difference(num1,num2):
    if num1 > num2:
        print (num1 - num2)

    elif num1<num2:
        print (num2 - num1)

    elif num1==num2:
        print ("There is no difference")



difference(num1,num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
try:
    num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))

    if num1 > num2:
        print (num1 - num2)    
    elif num1<num2:
        print (num2 - num1)
    elif num1==num2:
        print ("There is no difference")
except ValueError:
    print('Not a number');
```